# Add a new server to Gemfire cluster hosting a replicated region

Tags: replication, cluster-computing, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have a Gemfire cluster of 1 server that hosts the replicated region. I am using client-server architecture.

```
<region name="region_name">
    <region-attributes refid="REPLICATE" />
</region>
```

The region gets pre-loaded with data.

Then I add a new server to the cluster. I can see it in Pulse and in gfsh. Some new clients get connected to the  new server, but they receive empty data. 
**The data does not get replicated from the first server to a freshly started one.**

In cacheserver.log for the 2nd server I can see the lines like

```
Region region_name requesting initial image from fodbs-otc01(85584)<v60>:11033
region_name is done getting image from fodbs-otc01(85584)<v60>:11033
```

I would imagine it is the data replication from the 1st server, but no data seems to appear on the 2nd server.

Any solutions?

UPDATE: I noticed it has something to do with the index. I have an index defined as

```
<index name="businessDateIndex">
    <functional from-clause="/region_name" expression="businessDate" />
</index>
```

Everything works fine if the index is removed. But if if the index is enabled, it seems like the index does not get replicated, while the cache server still tries to use it. And hence - empty data from the newly started server.

Comment: I assume you have the cache.xml exactly the same on both sides with the region and index defined in both?

Comment: Yes, cache.xml is exactly the same on both servers.